# How to position Twitter follow-button on top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I am trying to position a Twitter follow-button on top of a background splash image using:

```
<style>
div.splash
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.twitter-follow-button
{
    position: absolute; [Edit: Copy and paste error. This used to read "position: relative"]
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>

<div class="splash">
    <img src="image_1.png">
    <a href="https://..." style="position: absolute; top: 320px; left: 225px;">
        <img src="image_2.png">
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:..." style="position: absolute; top: 258px; left: 500px;">Email</a>
    <a href="https://..." style="position: absolute; top: 320px; left: 225px;">Link</a>
    <a href="twitter_handle" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-dnt="true">
            Follow @twitter_handle
    </a>
</div>
```

But I cannot get the Twitter anchor to share space with the splash image.  Putting style="..." code in the Twitter anchor tag does not work either, even though it does for the other two anchors, one of which also displays an image.

EDIT:

This is the script Twitter provides for this button:

```
!function(d,s,id)
{
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id))
    {
        js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}
(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showcasing your problem?

Comment: Your code is not complete enough for me to be able to run it and see what the issue is. If you want elements to share space, in general you should look into using the CSS property `position: absolute;`.

Comment: I will try to put up a jsFiddle.  I assumed I had forgotten something really basic about layouts that would be obvious to someone else.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister: Sorry, I did try "position: absolute" first, just like the other two anchors and then tried "position: relative" after the fact and that's the code that got pasted in. Seems odd that the Twitter anchor would behave differently using the same style code.

Comment: @Schemer how did that work for you?

Comment: @Schemer did you have any luck?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a z index like so:

```
div.splash
{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there is no difference.

Comment: if you want the twitter button on top of the background then i taught the background should be relative and the twitter button absolute

Answer (score 2):

I rearranged your code somewhat. I don't know what your splash image so i have just used one of my own. Here is my latest [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcp40q6L/7/)

```css
#splash {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.twitter-follow-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
a.links1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  top: 258px;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
}
a.links {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 320px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash">

  <a href="twitter_handle" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-dnt="true">
    <img src="http://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Twitter-icon.png.png" width="30px" height="30px">Follow twitter_handle
    <a class="links" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="links1" href="#">Mailto</a>
    <a class="links1" href="#">Other Link</a>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The splash is just a rectangular .png and so is the image in the anchor that is politely sharing space with it. I tried this and it resulted in the same inline display problem but with the Twitter button now aligned with the top of the splash. This seems to be a clue. Why align with the top of the splash and not the viewport? Does your code include the script they provide?

Comment: @Schemer no but i could edit it to include the twittter javascript

Comment: I'm thinking the issue is the behaviour of insertBefore(). I can't post a jsFiddle because all of the links contain identifying information that is not public yet. :-/ Here is the link: https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons

Comment: @Schemer here is an updated fiddle. it won't sit to the left! http://jsfiddle.net/rcp40q6L/3/

Comment: Thanks so much for trying! I still can't get it to share space, even with your modifications. The button insists on behave like its own <div> and just refuses to overlap with the splash.

Comment: Another poster got upvoted for suggesting a z-index of -1, which didn't work. Neither does a z-index of +1. What a pain.

Comment: +/-1000 for the splash and button in any combination has no effect.

Comment: try putting your content in a separate div and then give it a z index. http://jsfiddle.net/rcp40q6L/6/

Comment: This does work. The problem is that I want to position the splash in the center of the viewport and then position the anchors relative to the splash. For the other, non-pathological anchors, this happens as a consequence of being positioned absolutely within the splash div. Moving this anchor to its own div means losing the ability to position it naturally within the splash div, doesn't it? It's been a while....

Comment: Hmm. "Absolutely" nothing seems to get them to share space. :-) Thanks so much for all of your help! I'll pick up again tomorrow and play around with your fiddle. It's late here and fatigue might be as much of a problem at this point as anything else. :-/